# Вывод данных н экран

Tags: javascript, php

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой и не знаю как её решить, подскажите пожалуйста.

Есть php-код:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT newyear FROM tb_image WHERE id = '$id'");
$image = mysql_result(0, 0, $sql);
echo "<img src = '$image'>
?>
```

И мне надо чтобы пользователь который разместил бы код у себя на сайте примерно такого вида:

```
<script src = "http://site.ru/newyear.php?id=1"></script>
```

и у него в том месте де будет установлен код, выводилась картинка которая будет получена из базы?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант проще

код для размещения `<img src='http://site.ru/newyear.php?id=1'>`

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT newyear FROM tb_image WHERE id = '$id'");
list($image) = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); //здесь может быть ваш код :), если у вас не jpeg
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($image));     
readfile($image);
?>
```

Если нужен именно `<script src = "http://site.ru/newyear.php?id=1"></script>`, то

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT newyear FROM tb_image WHERE id = '$id'");
list($image) = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo "document.write('<img src=\'http://site.ru/$image\'>')";

?>
```

Но лучше этот вариант не использовать.

А еще вы странно используете mysql_result.

Answer (score 0):

ваш скрипт должен отдасть саму картинку. Смотрите в сторону библиотеки GD

Answer (score 0):

Почему у вас эхо не закрыто?
Что за идиотское желание хранить картинки в базе?

Если так приспичило не проще сделать каталог типа /banners/
Сунуть туда index.php
.htaccess который бы перекидывал все запросы на index.php
и index.php который вытягивал бы картинку с базы и делал ее эхо (если надо отдавал нужный заголовок).

По моему достаточно прозрачно для конечного сайта т.к. запросы будут идти к виртуальным картинкам, которые физически находятся в базе.

Не смотря на бредовость идеи автора я попытался решить проблему.

Да и не говорите что то что я написал - бред, какой вопрос - такой ответ.

Comment: Яростно! Но не по делу.

Comment: Не соглашусь, представленный вариант как раз хорош. Ну а код - как нибудь без меня разберитесь не все же за вас делать.